# Looking for data that is a temporal/transient/dynamic network with hierarchical information and edge labels

Tags: data-request, network-structure, time-series

I am looking for a dataset that has a set of features.

- network: there are nodes/actors/users which send messages to other nodes as a subset in the network
- temporal/dynamic: there are time stamps to the messages sent between nodes so that the edges are 'transient'
- ranked nodes: there is some form of hierarchy in the network where nodes are ranked
- edge approval: that the edges/messages produced can be classified as either positive/negative.

The last two requirements are hard for me to find in datasets that I have seen. I am trying to test a new algorithm which needs a given hierarchy, and edges to be labelled as +1/-1 for good and bad. I thought of giving sentiment scores to some Twitter network for this edge approval but I am not sure how robust that would be and am not sure how I would make a hierarchy from it.

I imagined a network from primate studies but did not find it.